# Azure Equivalent for CodeDeploy

Tags: azure, travis-ci, aws-codedeploy

Right now, using AWS services we have a CI and deployment pattern that works well for us.

For every commit pushed to github, Travis-CI builds the project and runs tests, if tests pass, Travis uses CodeDeploy to deploy to staging (an AWS EC2). On tagged commits, if tests pass, deploy to production.

We are exploring using Azure, and we can't quite seem to figure out how to get the same pattern. In particular, we can't find the equivalent to CodeDeploy for Azure.

Does anyone have a similar pattern of CI and deployment that deploys to an Azure Virtual Machine?

According to Microsoft's [AWS to Azure services comparison](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services), Visual Studio Team Services correspond to CodeDeploy, but it seems like a very different tool and it is not clear to me if it can be put in our current pipeline.

Comment: Is it a .NET Core application?

Comment: It's a python web app.

Comment: You should be able to do this with VSTS (now called Azure DevOps).  [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-python) might be a starting point...

Answer (score 5):

Azure has a robust CI/CD pipeline which is much easier to use than CodeDeploy on AWS. It is called Build/Release pipelines under Azure DevOps. It allows you to configure multiple environments with build and release (deployment) stages for each. It also allows for easy configuration and interoperability with Azure Webapps/VMs and other resources available on Azure. Having recently switched from Azure to AWS, I definitely miss the ease of configuration and the intuitive UI on Azure DevOps.

Azure DevOps integrates a version control repository system, a agile style work items/boards which can also be used to configure your backlogs and iteration items. There is even a dashboard to integrate and monitor your work items and deployments across the team. So it is definitely much bigger than just a devops tool or CodeBuild.